# Perl LWP Curl Error: 'SSL peer certificate was not ok'

Tags: perl, curl, lwp

Here is my code:

```
my $lwpcurl = LWP::Curl->new(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0);
my $content;
$content = $lwpcurl->get($url);
```

I am getting this error:

```
`SSL peer certificate was not ok`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LWP::Curl](http://cpan.me/LWP%3a%3aCurl) doesn't accept `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`/`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` parameters for it's constructor!

Use [LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl](http://cpan.me/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3aNet%3a%3aCurl) instead:

```
use LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl ssl_verifyhost => 0, ssl_verifypeer => 0;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $content = $ua->get($url);
```

Note that LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl alters the default LWP::UserAgent behavior, so you still use `$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new`, while it uses `libcurl` internally.